# Выборка IP-адресов из одной таблицы

Tags: ip, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужно выбрать айпишники из таблицы Login_time.  
Нажимаю на таблице правой кнопкой мыши и выбираю создать новый селект.

```
SELECT 
      ,[key_id]
      ,[channel]
      ,[act_time]
      ,[address]
      ,[auth_result]
      ,[credential_type]
      ,[credential_id]
      ,[crypto_type]
      ,[java_version]
      ,[java_vendor]
      ,[hw_info_users_id]
      ,[failure_reason]
  FROM [ibank2].[ibank2].[login_time]
```

Вот куда-то сюда надо вставить айдишник клиента, чтобы выдалась вся информация, когда и с каких айпи клиент заходил.

Comment: В каком поле ip-адреса, а в каком идентификаторы клиентов? Можете показать одну строчку для примера?

Comment: Тебе, чтобы отфильтровать нужного по id, надо дописать WHERE id = @id.